# Path /WEB-INF/jsp/newportlet/view.jsp is not accessible by this portlet

Tags: java, security, jsp, liferay, file-access

Have tried to put portlet JSPs inside WEB-INF folder and met error

```
Path /WEB-INF/jsp/newportlet/view.jsp is not accessible by this portlet
```

Why this error occurs? Is it possible to allow portlet to access WEB-INF? Is it possible to close accessing portlet JSPs from web browser directly in the way other than putting them inside WEB-INF?

**UPDATE 1**

I have just created a new portlet by wizard. No code written, just JSP location set. The location worked for wizard, because it put JSP there. The location is reflected in `portlet.xml` as a following subtag of `<portlet>` tag:

```
<init-param>
    <name>view-jsp</name>
    <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/newportlet/view.jsp</value>
</init-param>
```

The code of the class is empty:

```
public class NewPortlet extends MVCPortlet {
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code how you're accessing the jsp?

Comment: did you check that this folder (newportlet) has read permissions ?

Comment: @alfasin I am running Liferay under eclipse, so the rights should be the same all the time. If the wizard was able to create files, then they are accessible.

Comment: @mijer, please look an update; actually there is no code, just wizard template created.

Comment: @Dims it's very easy to check it: just put another JSP under the same folder and see if it's accessible. I think it's worth to "waste" ~1 minute to check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/10650549) topic

> I assume you don't use MVCPortlet (where you can't include files from WEB-INF directory by default).

Also have a look at the source code of [MVCPortlet.checkJSPPath(String)](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/javadocs/src-html/com/liferay/util/bridges/mvc/MVCPortlet.html) method. I believe you can override it, so it does not throw an exception.

Comment: Overriding helped, although I don't like this solution. It should be some recommended one.